# Sonar for Bitbucket failed, The 'component' parameter is missing

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket-cloud

I have trouble integrating sonar qube for my bit bucket cloud, it would be great if anyone could help me out with this.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: @karthikeayan still coudn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

For me downgrading Sonarqube to 7.6 resolved this issue.